# how can i control frames in opencv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

how can i control frames in opencv?
here you insert the url of a video in the internet/local and this streams it to you.but voice and video are not Coordinated.video is faster than voice :/

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer

def getVideoSource(source, width, height):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
    return cap

def main():
    url=input('enter url: ')
    sourcePath = url
    camera = getVideoSource(sourcePath, 720, 480)
    player = MediaPlayer(sourcePath)

    while True:

        ret, frame = camera.read()
        audio_frame, val = player.get_frame()

        if (ret == 0):
            print("End of video")
            break

        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (720, 480))
        cv2.imshow('Camera', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        if val != 'eof' and audio_frame is not None:
            frame, t = audio_frame
            print("Frame:" + str(frame) + " T: " + str(t))

    camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: maybe use `ffpyplayer` (instead of `cv2`) to get video frame - probably it is only way to synchronize it.

Comment: @furas would you please write down the code?i didn't understand actuallywhat you mean... thanks

Comment: opencv is for computer vision, not for video/audio sync stuff. So as you see, audio isnt supported at all and video has no direct timestamp support.

Comment: @Micka OK,any solution?

Comment: search for multimedia libraries like ffmpeg

Comment: @Micka thanks.i will check it out

Comment: `ffpyplayer` is wrapper on `ffmpeg` program and it should gives you audio and video frame and you should use it instead of `cv2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification of [the answer by @furas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122050/7305715):

```
player = MediaPlayer(video_path)

while True:
    frame, val = player.get_frame()
    if val == 'eof': 
        break # this is the difference
    if frame is not None:
        image, pts = frame
        w, h = image.get_size()

        # convert to array width, height
        img = np.asarray(image.to_bytearray()[0]).reshape(h,w,3)

        # convert RGB to BGR because `cv2` need it to display it
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        time.sleep(val)
        cv2.imshow('video', img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
player.close_player()
```

The difference is the explicit `break` once EOF is reached, which causes the program to terminate. To me, that's expected behavior, so I wanted to post this code in case someone wants that behavior as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't control when to play audio because it uses `SDL` to play it in separated thread but `get_frame()` gives tuple `(frame, val)` and `frame` is `(image, time_when_to_display_image)` and you should use this `time_when_to_display_image` to control when to display image.

And all this code doesn't need `cv2.VideoCapture()` to get frame.

I use `cv2` only to display it but you can use any GUI to create window to display it.

I use `current_time` to get next frame without using `time.sleep()` because video wasn't smooth.

BTW: You can use `player.set_size(720, 480)` to resize frame.

```
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

filename = 'video.mp4'

player = MediaPlayer(filename)
player.set_size(720, 480)  # resize it
#player.set_size(400, 300)

start_time = time.time()
frame_time = start_time + 0

while True:
    current_time = time.time()

    # check if it is time to get next frame
    if current_time >= frame_time:

        # get next frame
        frame, val = player.get_frame()

        if val != 'eof' and frame is not None:
            image, pts = frame
            w, h = image.get_size()

            # convert to array width, height 
            img = np.asarray(image.to_bytearray()[0]).reshape(h,w,3)

            # convert RGB to BGR because `cv2` need it to display it
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

            cv2.imshow('video', img)

            frame_time = start_time + pts

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
player.close_player()
```

---

**EDIT:** I found that `get_frame()` gives `(frame, val)` and this `val` can be used in `time.sleep(val)`. And probably it should sleep before displaying frame, not after displaying it.

```
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

filename = 'video.mp4'

player = MediaPlayer(filename)
player.set_size(720, 480)
#player.set_size(400, 300)

while True:
    frame, val = player.get_frame()
    if val != 'eof' and frame is not None:
        image, pts = frame
        w, h = image.get_size()

        # convert to array width, height 
        img = np.asarray(image.to_bytearray()[0]).reshape(h,w,3)

        # convert RGB to BGR because `cv2` need it to display it
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        time.sleep(val)
        cv2.imshow('video', img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
player.close_player()
```

---

**EDIT:** Code using `tkinter` to display it.

```
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

# -- functions ---

def update_frame():
    global photo  # solution for BUG in PhotoImage

    frame, val = player.get_frame()
    if val != 'eof' and frame is not None:
        image, pts = frame
        w, h = image.get_size()

        data = image.to_bytearray()[0]
        img = Image.frombytes("RGB", (w,h), bytes(data))
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        time.sleep(val)
        label['image'] = photo

    root.after(1, update_frame)  # again after `1ms` without blocking `mainloop()`

# --- main ---

filename = 'video.mp4'

player = MediaPlayer(filename)
player.set_size(720, 480)
#player.set_size(400, 300)

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

root.bind('q', lambda event:root.destroy())

update_frame()

root.mainloop()
player.close_player()
```